# Phoenix framework / Elixir adding Geospatial fields

Tags: elixir, geospatial, phoenix-framework

I am trying to add geospatial fields to the phoenix framework with https://github.com/bryanjos/geo package. I want to access through Ecto models so I followed the outlined of adding the line:

```
Postgrex.Types.define(
  MyApp.PostgresTypes,
  [Geo.PostGIS.Extension] ++ 
    Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.extensions(),
  json: Poison)
```

as outlined in the readme file. Problem is that it doesn't specify exactly where to add this so I added it to config/dev.exs

I then added the line:

```
types: MyApp.PostgresTypes
```

to my dev repo config file `config/dev.exs` as specified.

I then get the error that `Postgrex.Types.define` and `Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.extensions` functions do not exist (as the modules are reportedly unavailable.

I then try to put the following lines in `lib/myapp/myapp.ex` as I suspect it has something to do with process intialization.

```
Postgrex.Types.define(
  MyApp.PostgresTypes,
  [Geo.PostGIS.Extension] ++ 
     Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.extensions(),
  json: Poison)
```

However when I add more fields do another migrate with mix ecto.migrate,
I get an error:

> function `Jobflo.PostgresTypes.find/2` is undefined (module `Jobflo.PostgresTypes` is not available.

I don't think it should be this hard and suspect I am making an obvious mistake. Anyone familiar with setting up Geo stuff with Phoenix would be greatly appreciated. 
Thankyou.

Comment: Post relevant code here; don't link your post to github, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this a tad confusing when I upgraded geo a few months ago.

Create a file called `lib/postgres_types.ex` with the following in it:

```
Postgrex.Types.define(
  Myapp.PostgresTypes,
  [Geo.PostGIS.Extension] ++ Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.extensions(),
  json: Poison
)
```

In your config file (in my case, `"#{Mix.env}.exs"`) make sure your config looks like this:

```
config :myapp, Myapp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  types:   Myapp.PostgresTypes,
  username: "jbloggs",
  password: "abc123",
  database: "api",
  hostname: "db_hostname.com",
  pool_size: 10
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Brilliant thankyou! Is this documented or an Elixir convention? Cheers

Comment: @Simon neither - it is documented, its just that the documentation isn't very clear to me (and you too I guess!)

Comment: Hi. Is this still valid in 2019?
Not working for me.